# Why wouldn't current flow if a circuit is connected between batteries but the other ends of the batteries are disconnected?

Tags: batteries

[image: Standard Zinc Copper cell lighting up a bulb, with all the relevant chemical behaviour labelled and explained.]
[image: Connecting the bulb between two such cells, leaving the other ends open.]
This light bulb is connected between positive and negative terminals, but no current flows. Why does this not work?

Comment: Is Volta battery without salt bridge possible?

Comment: You seem to be thinking that batteries are working on magic. What is really happening is that battery chemistry is automatically trying to maintain a certain voltage. For example, Zn$\to\text{Zn}^{2+}+2e^-$ until a certain voltage is created, where it stops, and if you go over that voltage, it will instead do Zn$^{2+}+2e^-\to$Zn, i.e. it is possible to make rechargeable batteries. In your setup, the electrons will pile up on the open Zn and be lacking on the open Cu, making a voltage difference just enough to stop the reaction. Only if you connect the open ends will the voltage drop allow flow

Comment: We call them circuits because current flows in circles. Where's your circle?

Answer (score 1):

> This light bulb is connected between positive and negative terminals, but no current flows. Why does this not work?

There is an unfortunate tendency for new students and teachers of new students to focus on the electrons in the metal as though current is always electrons in metal. In the functioning and connected battery there is a current of electrons in the metal, but there is also a current of sulfate ions in the electrolyte. This current of sulfate ions is every bit as important as the current of electrons in the metal.

You do not expect the current to flow when the metal wire is disconnected because then the electrons cannot flow. So why would you expect current to flow when the electrolyte is disconnected so the sulfate ions cannot flow? The only reason for that expectation is the common teaching failure that focuses on electrons as though they are the only important charge carrier. This is usually accompanied by some joke about how the charge convention assigning a negative charge to the electron is "wrong".

The reason that the current does not flow in the second example is that the electrolyte is disconnected. That blocks current flow just as surely as disconnecting the wire, and for the same reason. With either path disconnected (wire or electrolyte) the chemical reaction at the electrodes quickly comes to equilibrium where it cannot proceed because one of the products of the reaction accumulates at the electrode (or equivalently one of the reactants is depleted). The products must be removed in order for the reaction to continue. That includes both the products in the metal as well as the products in the solution.